# Pegar todo conteúdo de uma div e escrever no começo de um arquivo

Tags: php, html5

Eu estou fazendo um sistema de criação de postagens, na qual o usuário, antes de salvar a postagem, pode visualizar a mesma. A visualização funciona perfeitamente, capturando os valores dos inputs da página de edição.
Agora como eu faço pra pegar o conteúdo da div `.post` e jogo no início do meu `posts.php`, quando o usuário clicar no botão de salvar.

```
        <div class="posts">
            <?php
                echo "<div class='post $tipo $cor'>
                <div class='post-title'>
                    <h2>$titulo</h2>
                </div>                               
                <div class='post-subtitle'>
                    <h3>$subtitulo</h3>
                </div>
                <div class='post-content'>
                    $conteudo
                </div>"
            ?>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu usaria um form com os dados em um campo hidden:

```
    <form action='posts.php' method="post">
        <input type='hidden' name='tipo' value='<?=$tipo?>' />
        <input type='hidden' name='cor' value='<?=$cor ?>' />
        <input type='hidden' name='titulo' value='<?=$titulo?>' />
        <input type='hidden' name='subtitulo' value='<?=$subtitulo?>' />
        <input type='hidden' name='conteudo' value='<?=$conteudo?>' />
        <input type='submit' value="Salvar" />
    </form>
```

E como escrever a postagem com os valores no início do posts.php? 
Pode usar o array $_REQUEST ou $_POST, usando como indice o atributo 'name' do formulário enviado:

```
    echo $_REQUEST['tipo'];
    echo $_REQUEST['cor'];
    echo $_REQUEST['titulo'];
    echo $_REQUEST['subtitulo'];
    echo $_REQUEST['conteudo'];
```

Comment: E como escrever a postagem com os valores no início do `posts.php`?

Comment: Bom dia @Daniel, se a minha sugestão te ajudou, poderia marcá-la como resposta?

Comment: Obrigado @DanielBonifácio

Answer (score 0):

Se for o que eu tou pensando de acordo com suas palavras, você pode tentar criar um formulário com uma textarea, e o editor vai colocando o texto lá! E ao clicar no botão Preview (por exemplo), você pode enviar esses dados da textarea e título etc, através de metodos post pro posts.php!

Na pagina posts.php você pode construir um design de acordo com o seu painel lá, e pode colocar vários tipos de posts, como o título do post, a descrição, informações sabe!

Basta criar um formulário, e no botão preview, redireciona para a posts.php onde mostra todas as informações necessárias, e depois o editor pode voltar e os dados ainda estarão lá! (Possivelmente).

Um exemplo da posts.php:

```
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
//e por aí vai
```

Para escrever esses dados:

```
    echo ($titulo);
    echo ($texto);
// e por aí vai
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, confesso que não entendi claramente o que você está querendo fazer.

Mas acredito que se resolva assim

Você vai guardar em uma variável o HTML pronto, colocar em um `input type="hidden"` e mandar via post para a página `posts.php`

```
<div class="posts">
    <?php
        $var = "<div class='post $tipo $cor'>
        <div class='post-title'>
            <h2>$titulo</h2>
        </div>                               
        <div class='post-subtitle'>
            <h3>$subtitulo</h3>
        </div>
        <div class='post-content'>
            $conteudo
        </div>";
    ?>
    <form action="posts.php">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$var?>" id="posts" name="posts">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
</div>
```

Lá no seu `posts.php` você faria assim

```
<?php 
    echo $_POST['posts'];
 ?>
```